# Change date format with vba

Tags: excel, vba, date

I would like to change the date format of a cell with VBA, but I have no idea for that. Let take below as our example, Column A is the input and Column B is the output as it must be in Thai Calendar...

My goal is extracting the value in Column A of Sheet1 to many Sheets with the converted Date...

[image]

Comment: Excel cannot convert a date from one calender to another, you will need to calculate that yourself. If you just want to format a cell have a look at the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat). Also the macro recoder might help here.

Comment: On Excel it is not possible, on MS Project it is an option. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjcalendartype

Comment: Did either of the two answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can copy data from cell 'A1' to 'B1' and convert date type to Thai.

> ```
> Dim mydate As Date 'create date variable
>
>     mydate = Range("A1").Value 'copy date value from Cell A1
>     Range("B1").Value = mydate 'paste date value into cell B1
>     Range("B1").NumberFormat = "[$-th-TH,107]d mmmm yyyy;@" 'convert copied format to Thai
> ```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for that I have low rep to comment.
date change is not a code issue. 
change from western date to buddadate is adding 543 yearsto western date
as excel using the number for the date.
1 equals to 1900-01-01
2 equals to 1900-01-02
43752 equals to 2019-10-14

you need to add 543 years to western date
put this on b1 cell.

=A1*1+543*365+rounddown(543/4,0)

remind that leap year comesevery 4 years so that you could adjust +rounddowns() part to correct date